# BindView of Butterknife on fragments @onclick NullPointError

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, butterknife

```
public class InputFragment extends Fragment {
    public ContractMVP.start start;
    void  setPresenter(ContractMVP.start start){
        this.start=start;
    }
    @BindView(R.id.Start_btn)Button btn;
    @OnClick(R.id.Start_btn) void setBtn() {
        start.start();
    }

    public static InputFragment newInstance() {
        return new InputFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_input, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,v);

        return v;
    }
```

I get `NullpointException` when ever I try to click the Button. When I debug it says `start=null`,
but when I use traditional `findViewByid` it works fine

Comment: If `start` is indeed null then it seems you're forgotten to call `setPresenter()`.

Comment: where you are using setPresenter

Comment: on the mainActivity ...actually there are two fragments involved here@Dory

Answer (score 2):

Did you add both dependences

> compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
>   annotationProcessor'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

Also check XML view `Id` and `R.id.(yourId)`